# How to convert a list into float for using the '.join' function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to compress a file into a list of words and list of positions to recreate the original file. My program should also be able to take a compressed file and recreate the full text, including punctuation and capitalization, of the original file. I have everything correct apart from the recreation, using the map function my program can't convert my list of positions into floats because of the '[' as it is a list.

My code is:

```
text = open("speech.txt")
CharactersUnique = []
ListOfPositions = []
DownLine = False

while True:
    line = text.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    TwoList = line.split()
    for word in TwoList:
        if word not in CharactersUnique:
            CharactersUnique.append(word)

        ListOfPositions.append(CharactersUnique.index(word))
    if not DownLine:
        CharactersUnique.append("\n")
        DownLine = True
    ListOfPositions.append(CharactersUnique.index("\n"))

w = open("List_WordsPos.txt", "w")
for c in CharactersUnique:
    w.write(c)
w.close()

x = open("List_WordsPos.txt", "a")
x.write(str(ListOfPositions))
x.close()

with open("List_WordsPos.txt", "r") as f:
    NewWordsUnique = f.readline()
    f.close()

h = open("List_WordsPos.txt", "r")
lines = h.readlines()
NewListOfPositions = lines[1]

NewListOfPositions = map(float, NewListOfPositions) 

print("Recreated Text:\n")
recreation = " " .join(NewWordsUnique[pos] for pos in (NewListOfPositions))
print(recreation)
```

The error I get is:

```
Task 3 Code.py", line 42, in <genexpr>
recreation = " " .join(NewWordsUnique[pos] for pos in (NewListOfPositions))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['
```

I am using Python IDLE 3.5 (32-bit).  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `NewListOfPositions` is a `map` object, casting every character in `lines[1]` to a float. When you try to iterate through it, it will error when it reaches something that can't be converted to a `float`. `lines[1]` evidently contains the character `[`, which can't be cast to a float.

Comment: Why do you write the values and positions to a file and read them again immediately after? Just use your original data! Also: you can't use a float as an index to a list.

Comment: Two things, first `VariableNamesLikeThis` are generally reserved for classes in Python, and there is a mismatch between your description of the problem and your code: you say 'list of words and positions' but your code attempts to break it down to *characters*.

Comment: @Wombatz this sounds like a homework problem. They don't really have a 'reason' per se. After all, plenty of compression algorithms already exist.

Comment: @Wombatz the task asks me to write two lists to a file and then use the two lists from the file to recreate the original text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix ----> TypeError: string indices must be integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278631/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Comment: @NoctisSkytower it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to turn the position values in the `list` into floats, since they `list` indices, and those must be integer? I suspected this might be an instance of what is called the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/150985).

I also found your code difficult to understand because you haven't followed the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In particular, with how many (although not all) of the variable names are `CamelCased`, which according to the guidelines, should should be reserved for the class names.

In addition some of your variables had misleading names, like `CharactersUnique`, which actually [mostly] contained **unique words**.

So, one of the first things I did was transform all the `CamelCased` variables into lowercase underscore-separated words, like `camel_case`. In several instances I also gave them better names to reflect their actual contents or role: For example: `CharactersUnique` became `unique_words`.

The next step was to improve the handling of files by using Python's `with` statement to ensure they all would be closed automatically at the end of the block. In other cases I consolidated multiple file `open()` calls into one.

After all that I had it almost working, but that's when I discovered a problem with the approach of treating newline `"\n"` characters as separate words of the input text file. This caused a problem when the file was being recreated by the expression:

```
" ".join(NewWordsUnique[pos] for pos in (NewListOfPositions))
```

because it adds one space before and after every `"\n"` character encountered that aren't there in the original file. To workaround that, I ended up writing out the `for` loop that recreates the file instead of using a list comprehension, because doing so allows the newline "words" could be handled properly.

At any rate, here's the resulting rewritten (and working) code:

```
input_filename = "speech.txt"
compressed_filename = "List_WordsPos.txt"

# Two lists to represent contents of input file.
unique_words = ["\n"]  # preload with newline "word"
word_positions = []

with open(input_filename, "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in unique_words:
                unique_words.append(word)
            word_positions.append(unique_words.index(word))

        word_positions.append(unique_words.index("\n"))  # add newline at end of each line

# Write representations of the two data-structures to compressed file.
with open(compressed_filename, "w") as compr_file:
    words_repr = " ".join(repr(word) for word in unique_words)
    compr_file.write(words_repr + "\n")
    positions_repr = " ".join(repr(posn) for posn in word_positions)
    compr_file.write(positions_repr + "\n")

def strip_quotes(word):
    """Strip the first and last characters from the string (assumed to be quotes)."""
    tmp = word[1:-1]
    return tmp if tmp != "\\n" else "\n"  # newline "words" are special case

# Recreate input file from data in compressed file.
with open(compressed_filename, "r") as compr_file:
    line = compr_file.readline()
    new_unique_words = list(map(strip_quotes, line.split()))
    line = compr_file.readline()
    new_word_positions = map(int, line.split())  # using int, not float here

words = []
lines = []
for posn in new_word_positions:
    word = new_unique_words[posn]
    if word != "\n":
        words.append(word)
    else:
        lines.append(" ".join(words))
        words = []

print("Recreated Text:\n")
recreation = "\n".join(lines)
print(recreation)
```

I created my own `speech.txt` test file from the first paragraph of your question and ran the script on it with these results:

```
Recreated Text:

I have to compress a file into a list of words and list of positions to recreate
the original file. My program should also be able to take a compressed file and
recreate the full text, including punctuation and capitalization, of the
original file. I have everything correct apart from the recreation, using the
map function my program can't convert my list of positions into floats because
of the '[' as it is a list.
```

Comment: Wow. This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per your question in the comments:

You will want to split the input on spaces. You will also likely want to use different data structures.

```
# we'll map the words to a list of positions
all_words = {}
with open("speech.text") as f:
    data = f.read()

# since we need to be able to re-create the file, we'll want
# line breaks
lines = data.split("\n")
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    words = line.split(" ")
    for j, word in enumerate(words):
        if word in all_words:
            all_words[word].append((i, j)) # line and pos
        else:
            all_words[word] = [(i, j)]
```

Note that this does not yield maximum compression as `foo` and `foo.` count as separate words. If you want more compression, you'll have to go character by character. Hopefully now you can use a similar approach to do so if desired.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be altered to fit mine